# Two Weapon fighting with whip

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I want to use a whip to attack and/or trip or disarm, Then move in with an axe or other weapon for damage on the prone opponent ( or to have if someone closes, my DM still plays by the rules that a whip is a reach weapon and cannot be used against an adjacent square)
So Whip in main hand and weapon in off hand? 
or Whip in off hand and weapon in main hand?

AND  the big question

Do I need two-weapon fighting feat tree, if I am not going to use both at the same time?

Comment: @FrancisJohn Please use answer posts to answer, and save commenting for messages intended to help fix posts. Thanks!

Comment: Do you insist on not using both at the same time or did you just thought it will be more easy no to do it ? Remember you can do a 5-foot-step toward your opponent in the middle of your full-round action to finish him with your axe.

Comment: This isn't totally related, but the whip rules state: "The whip is treated as a melee weapon with a 15-foot reach, though you don't threaten the area into which you can make an attack. In addition, unlike most other weapons with reach, you can use it against foes anywhere within your reach (including adjacent foes). So RAW, your DM is wrong about the reach thing.

Answer (score 4):

**You don't need the feats.  The hands don't matter.**

Pathfinder *only* draws a primary hand / offhand distinction when fighting with two weapons in the same round.  (Whether you can change which hand is your offhand each round or if one hand is always primary and the other always your offhand, the rules are silent about; but that won't matter in your case.)  When you're attacking with only one weapon in a given round, there is no offhand or offhand penalty.

Unless your GM changes that, of course.  I wouldn't, personally - you're already sacrificing the ability to use shields and two-handed weapons (and presumably a feat or special feature to get whip proficiency) for just a little versatility, AND they've already house-ruled an additional penalty on top of your "can't hit 50% of the Bestiary because armor" whip (it's not a reach weapon, it's a ranged weapon!), but they could.

Comment: What do you mean at the end when you said "can't hit because armor?"

Comment: A whip deals no damage to any creature with an armor bonus of +1 or higher or a natural armor bonus of +3 or higher.

Comment: Never used a whip, didn't realize that. Can you still trip/disarm them?

Comment: @FrancisJohn Yes, just can't do damage. On-hit magic works too, so *spell storing* or *flaming* etc.

Comment: There are methods of bypassing the inability do deal damage with a whip, if you want. Using a [Scorpion Whip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/whip-scorpion/) or the Feat [Whip Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/whip-mastery-combat/) come to mind.

Comment: The greatest benefit of taking TWF for this build would be that it allows you to CMB with your whip, 5 foot step into melee, then swing with your other weapon for your remaining iterative attacks, saving a little on action economy. It's up to you if that's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Two Weapon Fighting feat tree.  You could:

1. use the whip in your primary hand, then
2. drop the whip once your opponent is tripped/prone/disarmed, then
3. draw the axe or other weapon for free as part of movement if your base attack bonus is +1 or higher, then
4. move to close.

With the [Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final) feat you can draw the subsequent weapon as a free action.  It's overkill to take that feat,  unless you truly want to use your move action for something else other than drawing a weapon.

This allows you to use your secondary hand for a shield or map or torch or whatever.

Comment: You do not need Quick Draw if you are moving to close. If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may draw a weapon as a free action combined with a regular move.

Comment: That's a good point, and one I had forgotten. I'm going to edit my answer to re-tool the reference to Quick Draw.

Comment: While I disagree with the need to put the second weapon in the first hand anyway (hence my separate answer), I would point out that since the OP has already specified he's holding a weapon in each hand, he'll *never* need Quick Draw since switching a weapon between hands is a free action as long as the other hand is free.